# When I login on a ubuntu server via ssh for my mac, I get the wrong PATH setting on the linux account

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, path

I have an ubuntu server, with a rails application. When I access directly that server, I have no problem with the setting of the path for my rails commands, but when I log trough ssh for my iMac, I got differents setting, so, for example, the

```
wich rails
```

return

```
home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
```

but from ubuntu return

```
/user/local/bin/rails
```

who is the correct one.

Anyone knows how to set correctly those values for ssh?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is not the problem, and does not need to be further configured, what you're seeing is symptomatic of not having the path correctly setup. Try this: echo $PATH both at local machine and using ssh.

When you installed rails by hand, where did you extend the path to include /usr/local/bin ? You need to make sure your terminal is sourcing that file, which it obviously is not.

EDIT: There are many places where you can add things the path, that is why I was asking you where did you added it, in .profile? Knowing that it would be easy to fix. I would personally do it in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

just realize that this only makes sense if bash is your terminal.

Comment: effectively, the PATH are differents, how can I make sure that my terminal is sourcing that file correctly?

Comment: @Nisanio: I've edited my answer a little bit.